# How to confine generic collections to specific types in C#?

Tags: c#, collections, types, generic-collections

I can define an arraylist `private ArrayList keyBuffer = new ArrayList();` just fine, and the compiler has no problems with it. But as soon as I attempt to constrain it to a desired datatype, ie. `private ArrayList<string> keyBuffer = new ArrayList<string>();`, it lights up the `ArrayList<string>` part and gives me the error "The name `ArrayList' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: The **C#** `ArrayList` is not generic... use `List<T>`.

Comment: You mean `List<T>`, not `ArrayList<T>` - pretty sure there is no generic array list, which is in `System.Collections.Generic`, as zerkms pointed out.

Comment: I am `using System.Collections.Generic`. I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Maurdekye - **Because there is no `ArrayList<T>`.  Doesn't exist.**  You need to use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: ArrayList is in `System.Collections`, but is not under `System.Collections.Generic`. Right-click it and choose "Goto Definition" (or press F12 on it) and you will see the namespace it's in.

Comment: Just substituted it for a List, and it seems to work. I guess transitioning from Java isn't all cookies and ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

Using the generic collection construct `List` instead of `ArrayList` allows type contraints, as is stated in the comments on the top post.. This is a common problem that programmers transitioning from Java to C# face.

Comment: Not much of a problem - just read the documentation. Don't assume that classes in .NET have the same name as the equivalent Java classes.